# get a string variable with quotation marks in getElementById inside a innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to get a value with quantity id. This code is in JavaScript and when it runs i the quotation in the id quantity is like this  `"quantity'` and i think this is the problem. can anyone suggests what to use to get the id like this `"quantity"`

```
tab.innerHTML += "<input  type='button' onclick='AddtoCart(document.getElementById('quantity').value;);' />";
```

Comment: You wouldn't have quoting issues if you used external event handling ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Escaping_characters) the quotes. Like:

```
tab.innerHTML += "<input  type='button' onclick='AddtoCart(document.getElementById(\"quantity\").value;);' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would ***HIGHLY*** suggest not using inline JavaScript.  As you can already see, it's causing you trouble.  It's only going to cause you more trouble in the future.

Instead make your button like so:

```
tab.innerHTML += "<input type='button' class='addToCart' />";
```

Then elsewhere in your code:

```
tab.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var classes = e.target.className.split(' ');

    if(classes.indexOf('addToCart') >= 0){
        AddtoCart(document.getElementById('quantity').value);
    }
});
```

This is similar to how jQuery handles "delegated" events.